# I want to set onClicklistener for an imageView on a cardView that is not present on particular xml file

Tags: android-studio

I have the main activity with its XML file that contains the `listview`
I have an item layout that includes `cardview` with the `imageview` and few relative layouts
I have an adapter that populates the `listview` with data from the database

[image: Overview of the page]

I have a table in a database, and an adapter that connects my `listview` now when I try to set an `onclicklistener` on the `imageview` as shown below (Image) it shows the error

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Kindly share code of clickListener

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SohaibAhmed Sorry The code is on my github repository https://github.com/rio225 if you can please visit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your imageView. Add following line in `getView` with other textView's.

```
ImageView icDownarrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icUparrow);
```

Remove the following variable globally (line:29)

```
ImageView icDownarrow,icUparrow;
```

#### Final Output will be

```
TextView timetxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timetxt);
TextView codetxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codetxt);
TextView moduletxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduletxt);
TextView stafftxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stafftxt);
ImageView icDownarrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icUparrow);

icDownarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (expandedLay.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new AutoTransition());
            expandedLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            icDownarrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cardView, new AutoTransition());
            expandedLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Really appreciates the help brother, it worked the app is running but still I don't have response when I click the down arrow (image view)

Comment: Can you place a `toast` inside on click before if condition and see, if the toast gets print or not

Comment: Again thanks the toast message was a big help I had mixed the id for the down arrow with the id for the up arrow

Comment: I tried but it said i need reputation first

Comment: try now, if it works

Comment: Still the same message brother